# React component export (html2canvas) to PNG misses all SVG icons

Tags: reactjs, svg, export, html2canvas

In my React app I'm using material UI (material-ui.com) with SVG icons. When I try to export components including SVG icons to PDF using [react-component-export-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-component-export-image), then all SVG icons are missing.

The SVG icons are defined such as:

```
// autogenerated from icon svg file "icons/Screenshot.svg", do not edit;
import * as React from 'react';
import { SvgIcon, SvgIconProps } from '@material-ui/core';
export const ScreenshotIcon = (props: SvgIconProps) => <SvgIcon {...props}><path d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z" fill="none" /><path d="M17 1.01L7 1c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v18c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h10c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V3c0-1.1-.9-1.99-2-1.99zM17 21H7v-1h10v1zm0-3H7V6h10v12zm0-14H7V3h10v1zM9.5 8.5H12V7H8v4h1.5V8.5zM12 17h4v-4h-1.5v2.5H12V17z" /></SvgIcon>;
export default ScreenshotIcon;
```

What am I missing that the SVG icons do not get rendered?

Comment: probably worth trying to convert them to data URLs

Comment: That's not a realistic suggestion, as there are many stock icons in the npm packages. The example I gave is just one to illustrate the SVG. In the end, I've ditched react-component-export-image and html2canvas for [html-to-image](https://github.com/bubkoo/html-to-image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution: use [html-to-image](https://github.com/bubkoo/html-to-image) instead which works out of the box with the SVG icons but also in more complex scenarios (I was asking here only about the first of a series of html-to-image bugs I was confronted with).

Moreover, html2canvas also is buggy in what could be described as "shadow" matte overlays appearing (no idea why it creates them) and arbitrary clipping.